# Syntax for Parametrized \newcommand

Tags: macros, renewcommand

I have a very basic question regarding `\newcommand`.

I would like to have a parametrized command of the form `\bla[x]` that gives as output a `\overset{x}{\rightarrow}`.

How can I achieve this?

Any feedback is most welcome.

Comment: Although any syntax is possible, the standard syntax for a command like this would use `{..}` not `[...]`, since the latter are typically used for optional arguments of a command. Do you have reasons to require the `[...]` form? But for some general explanation and examples of how `\newcommand` works see [\newcommand argument confusion](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/117358)

Comment: Why not `\xrightarrow{x}` (available with `amsmath`)?

Comment: @AlanMunn: Not at all, thus `{...}` would work just fine. However.... (see below – and thanks a lot for the link!)

Comment: @egreg: I didn't know about this command, which is perfect! Thanks a lot.